# Equivalence of smoothness and freeness of sheaf of differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

> Let $S$ be a regular locally Noetherian connected scheme, $f:X \to S$ a morphism of finite type with $X$ irreducible. Let $x \in X$ and $s = f(x)$ such that
>   $$ \dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \dim \mathcal{O}_{X_s,x} + \dim \mathcal{O}_{S,s} $$ 
>   If $\Omega_{X/S,x}$ is free of rank $\dim _x X_s$, then $f$ is smooth at $x$.
>
> **Proof**: Suppose $\Omega_X$ is locally free of rank$n$. There is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a closed immersion $U \to Z$ into an $S$-scheme $Z$ that is smooth at $x$ and $\Omega_{Z,x}$ is free of rank $n$. In particular, $\dim _x Z_s = n$. The *dimension formula* implies that $\dim \mathcal{O}_{Z,x} = \dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x}$ is regular and so integral. Therefore, $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is an isomorphism and $f$ is smooth at $x$.

The dimension formula to which it refers is

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a flat morphism of locally Noetherian schemes, $x \in X$, $y = f(x)$, then 
>   $$ \dim \mathcal{O}_{X_y,x} = \dim \mathcal{O}_{X,x} - \dim \mathcal{O}_{Y,y} $$

However, I'm not seeing how this is being applied. All we know about $f$ is that it is of finite type. We don't know that it is flat and even so, we don't even know whether the source $X$ is locally Noetherian. The formula therefore cannot be applied.

The given hypothesis about the dimensions seems to imply exactly the result of this formula. Namely, *if we assume that $f: X \to S$ is flat*, then rearranging terms in the dimension formula, we would get exactly the given hypothesis. However, the dimension formula, as it is stated in this reference, is not an if and only if. As such, it seems that the reference might be to the given hypothesis instead of the actual dimension formula. Nevertheless, I don't see how to get $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x}$ involved, instead of $\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$.

Where is there a map $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$? Is $Z$ a subscheme that contains $U$ and also contains $X$? I guess then we would have $i: X \to Z$ and $i^\# : \mathcal{O}_Z \to \mathcal{O}_X$. But then why would we need that $\mathcal{O}_{Z,z}$ is integral to claim that it is an isomorphism? Wouldn't it be true just by dimension consideration?

Finally, to conclude that $f$ is smooth at $x$, we would need to say that $f$ is flat at $x$ and the fiber $X_s$ are smooth. As mentioned above, we still seem to be missing flatness. Also, at no point in the proof were the fibers of the morphisms mentioned, so I am not sure how we are to conclude that the fibers are also smooth.

There are clearly some massive gaps in my reading of this proof. I have yet to see where any of the hypotheses are applied.